# how to convert a text file into comma separated values

Tags: shell

i have a text file that has text.txt

```
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee 
119                                         
fff/ggg/hhh/iii/jjj 
20
```

now how do i convert this output into 2 columns and store this in another text file

```
file                                                       count
aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee                                          119
fff/ggg/hhh/iii/jjj                                          20
```

i want to do this using shell script

Comment: Can you use `awk`?

Comment: yes i can use awk..but as i am a beginner in shell i am not aware of the proper syntax

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Can you post your attempts?

Comment: You need to show your attempts before seeking help in SO.

Comment: Also where is the comma separation in your expected output? Update your expected output with proper values, It is tab separated currently

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' fileName
```

The above N command is an example sed's multiline capability. N commands takes first_line and second_line and separates them by \n. The pattern is then applied to

> first_line\nsecond_line.

In the above example N command is followed by replace of \n with space. As a result the output becomes

> first_line second_line

Comment: Yes I agree that the code snippet should be accompanied with some explaination. Added that, missed updating it originally.

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash`:

```
( echo "file,count"
while read line #Read line by line
do
echo -n "$line," #Print one line, with a comma and without a newline
read line #Get the next line
echo "$line" #Print that line as second column
done < "inputFilename" ) > "outputFilename" #Redirect to output file
```

should do the trick (assuming you want actual comma separated values).